# Filebeat to monitor logs of several containers which are inside the containers

Tags: docker, logging, logstash, containers, filebeat

I have one question, Is there any way to ship the logs of each container where the log files are located inside the containers. Actually, the current flow will help to ship the log files which is located in the default path(var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log). I want to customize the filebeat.yaml to ship the logs from each container to logstash instead of the default path.

Answer (score 3):

If you can set your containers to log to stdout rather than to files, it looks like filebeat has an [autodiscover mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover.html) which will capture the `docker logs` of every container.

Another common setup in an ELK world is to configure logstash on your host, and set up Docker's logging options to send all output on containers' stdout into logstash.  This makes `docker logs` not work, but all of your log output is available via Kibana.

If your container processes always write to log files, you can use the `docker run -v` option or the Docker Compose `volumes:` option to mount a host directory on to an individual container's `/var/log` directory.  Then the log files will be visible on the host, and you can use whatever file-based collector to capture them.  This is in the realm of routine changes that will require you to stop and delete your existing containers before starting them with different options.

Comment: Thanks for your command David . But I really want to know if there any way to directly ship the containers usage log from within the container using filebeat.

Comment: No, host processes can't reach into Docker filesystem space, and poking around directly in `/var/lib/docker` is pretty much always the wrong answer.